# Appending html and reapplying changes Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to append an html snippet to the existing html using the following code. I am new to angular and I know I am doing something wrong (Since it does not work :D). Ideally I want to be able to append html from other html files and reapply the model on everything.

```
Dashboard = (function () {
    var scope;
    angular.module("MainApp", [])
        .controller("FirstCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Test";
        scope = $scope;
    }])
    var obj = {
        Load: function () {
            $.get("source.html")
                .done(function (data) {
                $('#container').html(data);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
    return obj;
})();
```

This is the html source file which I am trying to import:

```
<div>This is view one {{title}}</div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using jQuery.

Comment: is the html snippet dynamic?  You should probably be using a directive for this.

Comment: I also believe a directive would be best used here

Comment: I believe you will need to $compile html again to $scope to add the new html data. ($compile(element.contents())(scope))

Comment: So I will do a few things. 
1. As kanhai shah pointed, I would try compiling html. Not sure how that works but would give it a go.

2. Would try creating a directive. 

I will post whatever result I get to get you guys to help me out again :)